# Health Width Stops Adding When I Move My Mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a problem where I have a button when I click the button I increase my health rect width + 1  ***the problem is when I am holding the button with my mouse I want health rect to keep adding its width even if I am moving my mouse around the window but as soon as  I move  my mouse around my window the health rect stops adding***

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/0bdc4724f92a58f27427dc7dc037b7a6) I made it so if I stop holding my mouse to should stop adding  it but it some how detects when I move my mouse as well how would I fix that

here in my main loop I said if my mouse is over the speedbutton then it will keep adding else it should stop adding when I am not clicking the button anymore but when I move my mouse it stops adding my health as well

```
# our main loop
ble = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if speedbutton.isOver(pos):
                ble = True

                
        else:
           #[...]
            ble = False



   # if my ble is True then I will keep adding the health bar
    if ble:
        if health1.health < 70:
            health1.health += 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset `ble` when the mouse is not over the button or if the mouse is button is released (`MOUSEBUTTONUP` - see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
ble = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if speedbutton.isOver(event.pos):
                ble = True
                
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            ble = False

    # if my ble is True then I will keep adding the health bar
    if not speedbutton.isOver(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        ble = False
    if ble:
        if health1.health < 70:
            health1.health += 0.4
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed). `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down.

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to evaluate whether any mouse button is pressed:

```py
ble = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    mouse_buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    ble = any(mouse_buttons) and speedbutton.isOver(pos)

    # if my ble is True then I will keep adding the health bar
    if ble:
        if health1.health < 70:
            health1.health += 0.4
```